# ansible to store numeric value in register variable and check the condition statement

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using the below ansible playbook to check the root(/) size. if it's greater than 80%, then condition should be passed. But this is not working as expected. Can someone please help me with this.

```
  tasks:
- name: Check the space of the root
  shell: |
     df -h / | awk -F" " '{print $5}' | sed 's/%//g' | tail -1
  register: disk_output

- debug:
   msg: "the root is greater than 80%"
  when: disk_output.stdout > 80
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible uses Jinja2 tests and filters in conditionals.

You can use the `int` filter to convert the `disk_output.stdout` to integer and proceed to compare it with the 80 value:

```
  - debug:
      msg: "the root is greater than 80%"
    when: disk_output.stdout | int > 80
```

cheers